# Show Search Icon on Mouse over

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to when the mouse over my image show an icon search, but I'm not having the right results. Can anyone help? Any tip is welcome!

My html:

```
<article id="posts">
    <img class="search src="images/search.png"/>
    <img src="images/image1.jpg"  />
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum 1</p>
</article>
```

My jQuery:

```
var search = $('<img src="path/to/search/icon.png" class="search" />');
$('.search').hover( function(){
    $(this).append(search);
});
```

Comment: First of all correct this class="search src="images/search.jpng" your quotes are messed up. Where is .zoom?

Comment: var search = '<img src="path/to/search/icon.png" class="search" />'
also, where in your code is the class .zoom you apply the hover?

Comment: Thanks I was trying with different icon and then I change to other icon and I forgot to correct. But the problem is the same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure css effect you don't need js for that checkout css `:hover`

```
<article id="posts">
   <img class="search" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1/" />
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/2/" />
   <h2>Title 1</h2>
   <p>lorem ipsum 1</p>
</article>
```

the css

```
#posts img:nth-of-type(2){display:none}
#posts:hover img.search{display:none}
#posts:hover img:nth-of-type(2){display:inline-block}
```

[<kbd>THE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/gd8ba/28/)

or this

```
#posts img:nth-of-type(2){display:none}
#posts:hover img:nth-of-type(1){display:none}
#posts:hover img:nth-of-type(2){display:inline-block}
```

[<kbd>THE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/gd8ba/27/)

or this

```
#posts img.search +img{display:none}
#posts:hover img.search{display:none}
#posts:hover img.search +img{display:inline-block}
```

[<kbd>THE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/gd8ba/30/)

or add class `.hover` to the img after class `.Search`

```
<article id="posts">
   <img class="search" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/1/" />
   <img class="hover" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/2/" />
   <h2>Title 1</h2>
   <p>lorem ipsum 1</p>
</article>
```

the css

```
#posts img.hover{display:none}
#posts:hover img.search{display:none}
#posts:hover img.hover{display:inline-block}
```

or

```
#posts .hover{display:none}
#posts:hover .search{display:none}
#posts:hover .hover{display:inline-block}
```

[<kbd>THE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/cs7Lc/)

the simpliest way is this:

```
#posts:not(:hover) img.hover{display:none}
#posts:hover img.search{display:none}
```

[<kbd>THE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/cs7Lc/1/)

went you conbine it you have something like this:

```
#posts:not(:hover) img.hover,#posts:hover img.search{display:none}
```

or this:

```
#posts:not(:hover) .hover,#posts:hover .search{display:none}
```

[<kbd>THE DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/cs7Lc/2/)

Comment: Thank you but that way my image search.jpg appears aside <img src="images/image1.jpg"/> and I want that the search.jpg appears in the center of my image1.jpg and over image1.jpg.

Comment: @John23 Use an absolute positioning on your search image!

Comment: please check the demo

Comment: Thanks kougiland, exactly what I was trying. And now if you want to give some opacity effect or something, its necessary jquery right?

Comment: you are welcome, No you dont need jquery for that you can just use css opacity or if you want to animate it use css transition

Comment: Hm I found a little bug in your code because when I hover the image the search icon appears and then just leaves when I leave my article and not the image!

Comment: it's over now or you still need help?